# Timer can not find in scope

Tags: timer, invalidation

Where is it wrong with this code?

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func update() {

    if (counter > 0) {

        print(counter)
        counter = counter - 1

        progreesBar.progress = 1.0 - Float(counter)/Float(seconds)
    } 
    else {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

This code is not working as I expected. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by the title? Is part of it the literal error message?

Comment: Re *"is not working as I expected."*: What *do* you expect? Can you elaborate? For example, do you get a compiler error? Or does it happen when it runs? What happens?

Comment: What programming language? [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)? [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29)? `IB` may be for [Interface Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder), thus likely [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) or [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29).